# Convert the following model to quadratic integer programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Really having a hard time with this.....Convert the following model to a quadratic integer program:

> Maximize $Ay$ subject to $Bx \leq d$ and $y\in$  argmax $x^TMy.$

Does anyone have any idea? Or it is impossible? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by argmax $x^TMy$? Isn't a linear function typically unbounded or constant? What can you say about $M$?

Comment: You need to identify which symbols are scalars, which are matrices, which are continuous variables and which are integer (or binary) variables. In particular, if A is a matrix with more than one row, your objective function makes no sense.